# Return Jquery Validation Response inside Form Field

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, response

I am creating a popup jquery ajax comment form using the jquery validation plugin. Currently, the ajax is returning "this field is required" under the html form fields. How can I get the jquery to return this response inside the form fields as a blur/focus event?

Here is the js that controls the event:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#commentForm').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'process.php',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(returnedData) {
                        $('#commentForm').append(returnedData);
                    }
                });         
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

The html form is configured like:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="">
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <input id="cname" type="text" name="name" size="60" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
     <input id="cemail" type="text" name="email" size="60"  class="required email" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="curl">URL</label>
     <input id="curl" type="text" name="url" size="60"  class="url" value="" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
     <textarea id="ccomment" type="text" name="comment" cols="72" rows="8"  class="required"></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
     <div id="button2"><input class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Send Email"/></div>
   </p>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Would you copy the `returnedData` content please? As I remember, Validate plugin have an option to validate inputs one by one.

Comment: [Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element) shows how to set validation for an element. For Each element you need to

    `$('#cname').change(function(){$("#cmxform").validate().element( "#cname" );});`

Can you retrieve invalid element from `returnedData` ?

Comment: The returnedData just reads "this field is required." Unless the form validates, in which case it references process.php. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @Reza. But how do I return the validation response inside the form field?

Comment: You need to use the `errorPlacement:` option/handler.  I use it to put my errors inside qTip tool-tip bubbles.  Look towards the bottom of this page:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: Can anyone help me out with the proper syntax to add errorPlacement to my code using the submitHandler method above? I'm still not very advanced with jquery. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used a combination of the errorPlacement and fadeOut functionalities in jQuery. This is the working solution:

```
$('#commentForm').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(returnedData) {
                $('#commentForm').append(returnedData);
            }

        });
        return false;
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element).position({
            my: 'right top',
            at: 'right top',
            of: element
        });
        error.fadeOut(3000);
    },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just:

```
$('#commentForm #cname').val("This is required field");
```

Also you can use json. In this case, will be:

```
success:function(resp){
 if(resp["code"]=="err"){
   $('#commentForm #cname').val(resp["txt"]);
   //of course you need to use a loop to check all fields
 }
}
```